# My moto 4G play treats incoming messages as if they are group messages

Tags: sms, mms

For some reason the messenger app that came installed with my Moto 4G Play is treating some messages as if they are group messages.  Even though these messages were sent from a friend to only me when I receive them on my phone they show as a group message, with myself, the friend, and 1 other phone numbers not contained in my address book all showing.  If I try to reply back it sends the message to all those in the group message, including resending the message to me.

I have noticed this effect occurs when different people message me.  When someone messages me it may come in as a standard message or the odd group message, with no apparent indication for why some are converted to group messages and other's aren't.  The very first text I got was a group message like this, before I installed any apps other then those preinstalled by Amazon.

Has anyone seen this behavior before or know how I can prevent it from happening?

I'm running Android Marshmallow 6.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I discovered that the other random number that was being texted was my number.  I had been assigned a number by my carrier (republic wireless) and them immediately switched over to my previous phone number.  The number I believe republic wireless originally assigned me is the other number showing in group texts.

I believe the problem is therefore with republic wireless trying to send text both to the default number and the number I switched to.  Since these issues mostly showed up right after I changed phone numbers I would guess this is an intentionally attempt to ensure I get the text regardless of rather I switched over to my new number yet?  I'll wait to see if they stop doing this in a week after their confident my phone change over has stopped, and if not contact them.  However, in any case I think this is an issue with the carrier rather then the phone.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try uninstalling any updates, disabling and re-enabling the stock
   app. To do this go to settings > Apps > (your default messenger
   app).  Then press disable/uninstall updates.
2. Try using an alternative messenger such as WhatsApp , BlackBerry
   Messenger or Telegram. All  of these are available for free on the
   Google Play store.
3. Try resetting your phone by doing a "Soft-Reset". To do this go to
   settings > Backup and Reset > Factory Data Reset.  Be sure to backup
   all your data, app data, documents and media  on your phone before
   doing this.
4. If a soft reset doesn't work, try resetting your phone using a "Hard
   Reset". This completely reinstalls your Android system. Like before,
   be sure to backup all your data before doing this. Here's a link
   with instructions to do so [Motorola G 4G Factory Reset
   Instructions](http://factory-reset.com/wiki/Moto_G_4G)